# React routing is not working and always showing 404

Tags: reactjs, .net, react-router

My project is React + .NET. In development, the router is working fine, but when I publish this app and run it on local, react router is not working correctly. Once working, and next time never works and shows 404 error page.

```
<Routes>
  <Route element={<Home isAuthorized={isAuthorized} />} path="/" />
  <Route element={<SignIn />} path="/auth/sign-in" />
  <Route element={<SignUp />} path="/auth/sign-up" />
  {isAuthorized && (
    <Route
      element={<AccountSetting isAuthorized={true} />}
      path="/auth/account-setting"
    />
  )}
  {isAuthorized && (
    <Route
      element={<Games isAuthorized={true} />}
      path="/game/games"
    />
  )}
  <Route
    element={<MainGame isAuthorized={isAuthorized} />}
    path="/game/main-game"
  />
  <Route element={<About />} path="/about" />
  <Route element={<Features />} path="/landing/features" />
  <Route element={<FreeTrial />} path="/landing/free-trial" />
</Routes>
```

This is the React route code. I've been changed router to react-router, but not working too.

Comment: Where and how are you deploying and serving this React app? Can you [edit] to clarify this? The basic gist may be that the host/server needs to be configured to serve the root index.html file for all page requests into the app. See the CRA [deployment docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/) to get a broad sense what might need to specifically be configured for your hosting service/server environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think problem is within your server-side.
I'm sure you would use cors.

```
services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
        builder =>
        {
            builder.AllowAnyHeader()
                   .AllowAnyMethod()
                   .SetIsOriginAllowed((host) => true)
                   .AllowCredentials();
        }));
    

app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
```

Also check if your set MapFallbackToFile.

```
app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
```

Comment: I've changed cors like you gave me.
but still not working.